# I trying to start openerp-server with cron script

Tags: cron, shared-hosting, odoo, webfaction

I have a webfaction account and I install openerp-server 6.1.1, when a start the server from ssh session it's works, when I close the session it close the server too.
So I'm trying to start the server with cron.

From cron I call a script like this:

*/1 * * * * ~/webapps/openerp/start.sh

And the script:

## .bash_profile

openerp-server -c /home/usuario/webapps/openerp/server.conf

It doesn't work....

But if I call the script from the command line the server load ok....

It any way to debug this?

Comment: Please specify how you have installed the openerp server?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your cron command:

su -c "nohup openerp-server -c /home/usuario/webapps/openerp/server.conf &" - username

In this way you will have:

1.- Run the command with an user different from root.
2.- "man nohup" nohup left your app in the backgroung.

I hope it helps you.